# submitLoginForm() does not send the data to the authentication server - MobileFirst Cordova client

Tags: javascript, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to write a cordova hybrid application test application on MobileFirst platform. In my challenge handler, I have included a code to send a login information to my authentication server using submitLoginForm() java script API.

I check using wireshark if any auth request to my authentication server is getting generated, but it does not.

Can you please help me identify the issue with my code?

I can see the alert until **Inside handleChallenge3**, but does not see the alert for **Closing Challenge Handler**.

One more thing, I am trying to use isCustomResponse() API just to see what kind of challenge/response is coming to my challenge handler, but it seems not to be getting triggered. Has this been deprecated in MobileFirst Platform 8?

Thanks

```
var LtpaAuthChallengeHandler = function(){
      LtpaAuthChallengeHandler = WL.Client.createWLChallengeHandler("LtpaBasedSSO");

      LtpaAuthChallengeHandler.isCustomResponse = function(transport) {
        alert ("Inside isCustomResponse");
        return true;
      };

      LtpaAuthChallengeHandler.loginResponse = function(response) {
        alert ("Inside loginResponse");
        LtpaAuthChallengeHandler.submitSuccess();
        alert ("After loginResponse");
      };
      // handleFailure
      LtpaAuthChallengeHandler.handleFailure = function(error) {
         // WL.Logger.debug("Challenge Handler Failure!");
          if(error.failure !== null && error.failure !== undefined){
             alert(error.failure);
          }
          else {
             alert("Unknown error");
          }
      };

      LtpaAuthChallengeHandler.handleChallenge = function(challenge) {
        alert ("Inside handleChallenge");
        var msg = "";
    alert ("Inside handleChallenge1");
        var options = {
          "headers"     : {},
          "parameters"  : {
            "username" : "admin",
            "password" : "admin",
            'login-form-type' : 'pwd'
          }
        };
    alert ("Inside handleChallenge2");
        var loginUrl = "<URI for forms based auth of auth server>";
    alert ("Inside handleChallenge3");
        LtpaAuthChallengeHandler.submitLoginForm (loginUrl, options, LtpaAuthChallengeHandler.loginResponse);

        alert ("Closing Challenge Handler");
      };
    };
```

Comment: See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782988/iscustomresponse-api-available-or-not-mfpf8/37784687

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the credentials have been collected from the UI, use WLChallengeHandler's `submitChallengeAnswer()` to send an answer back to the security check.

`isCustomResponse()` is not applicable from MFP 8.0.

Refer to the Authentication and Security topic [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/).

Comment: Thanks Vivin for confirming that isCustomResponse() is no longer applicable from MFP 8.0. I saw this API in the following link: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.AbstractChallengeHandler.html

I am trying to send authenticate against a Reverse Proxy (my authentication server), which sits in between the mobile client and the MFP8 server. Once the authentication is complete, I can use the submitChallengeAnswer() to send the info etc. to the Security Check. Is submitLoginForm() API applicable for MFP 8?

Comment: For WL.Client.createWLChallengeHandler(securityCheckName);  method in MFP 8.0, submitLoginForm() is not applicable.

Comment: Thanks Vivin for the good catch. I was not able to see that to use submitLoginForm() the challengeHandler should be created using WL.Client.createChallengeHandler()

Comment: Just wanted to continue a little more on this topic. I just noticed that the API documentation for MFP8 does list isCustomResponse() API. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.AbstractChallengeHandler.html. Sorry for asking this once again. But is this API really not applicable from MFP8 onwards?